# Eclipse C++ & CMake Compile Error in Fedora 20

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake

I am wondering if anyone can help me or not. I try to compile application with CMake through Eclipse C++. However, I get the error message as below. It seems CMake can not find libicuuc.so.50. How do I link them into Eclipse? or any suggestion and advice are highly appreciated.

My OS system is **Linux Fedora 20**

```
=========================================================

     CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
 Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.8

 Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

=============================================================================
 Special targets provided by cmake.

 Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

 Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

 Produce verbose output by default.
VERBOSE = 1

 Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

 A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

=============================================================================
 Set environment variables for the build.

 The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

 The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

 The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

 Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

 The program to use to edit the cache.
CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake-gui

 The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /run/media/cooldean/SDCard/Application/jedox5/SourceForge/palo-code/molap/server/5.1

 The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /run/media/cooldean/SDCard/Application/jedox5/SourceCode/Linux64Bit

ICU_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE =/usr/bin/icu-config


=============================================================================
 Targets provided globally by CMake.

 Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    /usr/bin/cmake-gui -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

 Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

 Special rule for the target install
install: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install

 Special rule for the target install
install/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/fast

 Special rule for the target install/local
install/local: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/local

 Special rule for the target install/local
install/local/fast: install/local
.PHONY : install/local/fast

 Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/strip

 Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip/fast: install/strip
.PHONY : install/strip/fast

 Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Available install components are: \"Unspecified\""
.PHONY : list_install_components

 Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components/fast: list_install_components
.PHONY : list_install_components/fast

 Special rule for the target package
package: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Run CPack packaging tool..."
    /usr/bin/cpack --config ./CPackConfig.cmake
.PHONY : package

 Special rule for the target package
package/fast: package
.PHONY : package/fast

 Special rule for the target package_source
package_source:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Run CPack packaging tool for source..."
    /usr/bin/cpack --config ./CPackSourceConfig.cmake /run/media/cooldean/SDCard/Application/jedox5/SourceCode/Linux64Bit/CPackSourceConfig.cmake
.PHONY : package_source

 Special rule for the target package_source
package_source/fast: package_source
.PHONY : package_source/fast

 Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

 Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

 The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /run/media/cooldean/SDCard/Application/jedox5/SourceCode/Linux64Bit/CMakeFiles /run/media/cooldean/SDCard/Application/jedox5/SourceCode/Linux64Bit/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /run/media/cooldean/SDCard/Application/jedox5/SourceCode/Linux64Bit/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

 The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

 The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

 Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

 Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

 clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

=============================================================================
 Target rules for targets named clean.https.palo
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency to icuuc in your CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(<your_exectuable_target> icuuc)
```

Comment: Could you make an example for me? I am not quite familiar with C++ and Cmake. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I can be more precise if you put a minimalistic sample of your original code (CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: I have pasted some part of the code above. I am wondering if you could give me some suggest or not.

Comment: Please post the content of your CMakeLists, not the generated Makefile